# Why is my Windows Server 2003 system freezing under heavy disk I/O?

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization, ntfs

Using Windows Virtualization, I'm running a simple script on a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine that moves ~650,000 images from one directory to another.  It's little more than a simple loop that tests if the picture exists, and moves it if it does. Very simple, very I/O bound.

The system will suddenly freeze up while running this script, in what I believe is my host freezing after a static number of I/O calls. I even found a product that seems to be designed to handle this kind of I/O load, but I'm still having the problem, so I'm hoping someone can help me determine the root cause.

If this were Linux, I'd use something like `strace`, but on Windows, I'm not even sure how to start debugging this issue.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You problem most likely lies in the 650k files in a single directory. A reasonable limit is somewhere very south of 32k. (The technical limit is 4.3 billion, but as with most cases "if you have to ask, you're probably doing it wrong" - thedailywtf.com)